# how to Override operator <

Tags: c++, templates, operators, overriding

I'm trying to override operator < as the following :

inside Node :

```
bool operator <(const Node* other) {
  return *(this->GetData()) < *(other->GetData());
}
```

inside vehicle :

```
bool operator <(const Vehicle &other) {
  return this->GetKilometersLeft() < other.GetKilometersLeft();
}
```

invoking the operator :

```
while (index > 0 && m_heapVector[index] < m_heapVector[parent(index)])
```

vector definition :

```
vector<Node<T>*> m_heapVector;
```

I checked the call and it's not calling the overridden operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because you are comparing pointers,

You have to make it:

```
*m_heapVector[index] < *m_heapVector[parent(index)]
```

and adjust operator accordingly

```
bool operator<(const Node &other) const;
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  "adjust operator accordingly" means `Node<T>::operator<()` should take a reference, not a pointer, to `other`.

Comment: @Ben no problem, fixed operator

Comment: @Roy, notice operator should be `(const Node &other)`

Comment: @aaa hey thanks. i did what you said, now my operator looks like this : bool operator <(const Node &other) const {return *(this) < other;} and now i'm getting stack overflow.

Comment: @Roy on the other hand, I think your problem is you are having infinite recursion in your implementation of comparison operator

Comment: @aaa right, now no stack overflow but it's not entering the operator inside vehicle

Comment: Solved, by changing the operator in Node to be : bool operator <(const Node<T> &other) const {return *(this->GetData()) < *(other.GetData());} thanks all.